# Php song like counter

Tags: php, database, counter

This is more of a general question on how I would approach this.

I have a audio player. No data about songs is stored in the database. I would like to use database for counting likes for each song. My question is how would I organize this?

1.
If I list all my songs in database beforehand and add a column for like, then where would I keep track of user ip address? (not sure if there is a better way than using ip address?) So I prevent of same user voting multiple times.

2.
Every time user likes a song I would store {song title, like count, user ip} (maybe something else) in database. But then I would end up with multiple rows of same song with different user ip addresses, so how would I keep track of likes for every song in this case?

Answer (score 0):

> No data about songs is stored in the database

If you want to store data about each song, you should probably add a table for the songs.

> not sure if there is a better way than using ip address?

If you have a table with user IDs, use that because the same user can log on from different IPs, and different users can log on from the same IP.

As for database structure, what you proposed is probably the right answer.  Once you have a table set up for songs, have a dedicated column just for likes to you can retrieve it easily.

If you want to know which user liked which song (and when) then you need to make a new table like you suggested in your second point.  This is called a junction-table, and is used for many:many relationships (m:m).  There is no unique id.  It joins two tables with many keys (users:songs) and stores any relationship between the two.

> 2. Every time user likes a song I would store {song title, like count, user ip} (maybe something else) in database. But then I would end up with multiple rows of same song with different user ip addresses, so how would I keep track of likes for every song in this case?

Even if you end up with many rows of the same song, they are all unique since each has a different user liking it (and vice-versa, you can get all the songs a specific user liked).  You wouldn't need to store a like-count in here, since you can just count the number of records in the database.  {song title, user id, datestamp} would be fine.

Comment: table 1 {song title, like count}, table 2 {song title, user ip, datestamp}, they are only connected with song title? User likes, I populate both tables, if they hadnt liked already (based on user ip). (I know that same user can log on from different IPs, and different users can log on from the same IPs, but  I dont know if there is a better way to keep track of duplicate likes by same user). Why do I need datestamp?

Comment: table 1 {song_id, song_title, like_count}, table 2 {user_id, ...}, table 3 {song_id, user_id}.  Table three (song likes) connects the user table and the song table.  Every time a user likes a song, a new record is added to table 3.  If you're worried about duplicates, have php check if the record exists before adding it to table 3.